# VBA: Remove all the cells different to a specific font color

Tags: vba, excel, fonts, colors

I have an Excel where I only want to keep the values that are in determined font color, in this case, red.
I have a loop that is going cell by cell and checking if the cells comply with that condition. the code is:

```
 For nrow = 1 To frow
        For ncol = 1 To fcol

            If Cells(nrow, ncol).Font.Color <> RGB(255,0,0) Or Cells(nrow, ncol).Font.ColorIndex = 0 _
                Or Cells(nrow, ncol).Font.Color = xlNone Then
                    Cells(nrow, ncol).ClearContents
                End If

        Next
    Next
```

But it does not work correctly. There are cells that are not deleted. Apparently those cells have the font set as "automatic", and the condition "if" ignores those cells. I don't understand it. It should work because the value should be different to the one I indicate in the condition "if".

So my question is, how I can delete those cells that have set the font color in automatic? What do I need to do?

Comment: I would use the VBA constant for red vbRed rather than the RGB value just as a standard practice and try recording a macro when you do the delete manually and see how that code differs from yours.

Comment: I've found a turn around that have worked. Changing the perspective and do nothing if is the font color is red and else remove the contents.

Comment: If you're still interested: `If Cells(x y).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic`

Answer (score 0):

I tested following code for POC (only). I suspect its row counter issue after delete method.

Put following data in Sheet (column A):
1
2   (keep auto color)
3   (set color to red)
4   (set color to red)
5   (set any other color)
6

```
For counter = 1 To 6
    If Sheets.Item(1).Range("A" & counter).Font.Color <> 255 Then  ' if color is <> red
        If Sheets.Item(1).Range("A" & counter).Value = "" Then Exit For
        Sheets.Item(1).Range("A" & counter).Delete
        counter = counter - 1
    End If
Next
```